# querying on two id columns of same object

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Given a table like this:

```
Id_Table | Id_Object_A | Id_Object_B
```

and given two subset of ID_Object, I have to check this condition:

```
(ID_Object_A IN (1,2,3,4,5) AND ID_Object_B IN (6,7,8,9,10))
OR
(ID_Object_A IN (6,7,8,9,10) AND ID_Object_B IN (1,2,3,4,5))
```

What is the best way in terms of performance of doing it?

Comment: What dbms is this?  Are all of your object Id fields indexed?  Have you looked at the execution plan to determine if your query is optimized?

Comment: it would be sql server and yes there is a single index for each column

Answer (score 1):

The query optimizer should be smart enough for the most obvious solution to have an acceptable (near-optimal) performance:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (ID_Object_A IN (1,2,3,4,5) AND ID_Object_B IN (6,7,8,9,10))
   OR (ID_Object_A IN (6,7,8,9,10) AND ID_Object_B IN (1,2,3,4,5))
```

But SQL Server's real strength is in optimizing `JOIN`. Generate a table with all 50 possible combinations of the 10 numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE ReferencesAB (a int NOT NULL, b int NOT NULL)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Covering ON ReferencesAB (a, b)

INSERT INTO ReferencesAB
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) AS values1 (a)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)) AS values2 (b)

INSERT INTO ReferencesAB
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)) AS values1 (a)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) AS values2 (b)
```

Then join your table to the reference table:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN ReferencesAB r ON r.a = Id_Object_A AND r.b = Id_Object_B
```

For this to work out well, I think it is best to index `MyTable` on `(Id_Object_A, Id_Object_B)`.

Experiment with both approaches; study the query plans to figure out what works best with your table.